# How to avoid overriding compose defaults?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Based on this original code:

```
@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
fun Card(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    elevation: Dp = 1.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = shape,
        color = backgroundColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        elevation = elevation,
        border = border,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Am I overseeing something, or does the Kotlin language not allow me to call such a function without overriding the defaults?

Check this usage:

```
@Composable
private fun Item(item: itemEntity, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    val backgroundColor = if (item.readAt.isEmpty()) {
        MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = 0.1f)
    } else {
        // Do nothing?
    }

    Card(        
        backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    ) {
```

If I really wouldn't want to override the defaults I would need to have a bunch of if (x) Card(...). Obviously, I could check what default value the function currently sets and set that one in my else block at the beginning, but the default may change in future function revisions.

Comment: The language doesn't provide a way to do what you're trying to do. I think default values are not even inspectable at runtime because they are not part of the compiled code.

Comment: Default values should be available via reflection. However th penalty in term of performance and readability might not be worth it. It may be a good use-case for a compiler plugin